# Reading from database by calculating the percentage of string match

Tags: sql, database

'select X from Y where X like %sequence acceleration algorithem%'

we want to read this for example 'my algorithem for sequence acceleration'.
how we can do this in case of reading from database by calculating the percentage of string match?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sql has that feature. 
But You can do it by writing your logic.
Firstly get result by like %searchString%. This result is going to be a list.
Now iterate this list and remove (or add selected items into a new list) after checking every item by your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN X like '%sequence acceleration algorithem%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        / COUNT(*) AS ratio
FROM Y
```

This will give you the ratio of records whose column `X` contains the search string.

Note: if your table is empty, this query will generate an error since the denominator will be `0`. Use `NULLIF()` (or the-like in your RDBMS) to avoid the error:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN X like '%sequence acceleration algorithem%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        / NULLIF(COUNT(*), 0) AS ratio
FROM Y
```